# 2 - D Arrays: Soccer Team Roster

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble with my code reading the user input correctly. The user will type numbers formatted like this:

84 7

23 4

4 5

30 2

66 9

So the 2-D array is arrList[5][2]. So one vertical line of numbers is like variName[i][0] so 84, 23, 4, 30. And then the second vertical line of numbers is like variName[i][1], so 7,4,5,2. Hopefully, that makes sense. But my code is reading it as 84, 7, 23, 4 and repeats 4. And then stops.

```
int [][] player = new int [5][2]; // numElements = 5 elements = 5 people 
  //and each array includes 2 elements(jersey # and rating); 
  for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++) { // goes thru 2-D array 
     System.out.println("Enter player " + (i + 1) + "'s jersey number:");  
     if (player[i][0] >= 0 && player[i][0] <= 99) { // goes thru all players and their jersey number
        player[i][0] = scnr.nextInt(); // retrieves data from user for jersey # 
     } // end of if loop 
     System.out.println("Enter player " + (i + 1) + "'s rating:");  
     if (player[i][1] > 0 && player[i][1] < 10) { // goes thru all players and their rating 
        player[i][1] = scnr.nextInt(); 
     } 
     System.out.println(""); 
  }// end of for loop 
  System.out.println("ROSTER"); 
  for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++) { 
     System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + " -- Jersey number: " + player[i][0] + ", Rating: " + player[i][1]);
  }
```

It outputs:
ROSTER
Player 1 -- Jersey number: 84, Rating: 0
Player 2 -- Jersey number: 7, Rating: 0
Player 3 -- Jersey number: 23, Rating: 0
Player 4 -- Jersey number: 4, Rating: 0
Player 5 -- Jersey number: 4, Rating: 0

Instead of:
ROSTER
Player 1 -- Jersey number: 84, Rating: 7
Player 2 -- Jersey number: 23, Rating: 4
Player 3 -- Jersey number: 4, Rating: 5
Player 4 -- Jersey number: 30, Rating: 2
Player 5 -- Jersey number: 66, Rating: 9

I apologize for how long the question is, I just don't know if I am articulating the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your if conditions. Since Java `int` Arrays are initialized with 0 value, you will never enter the the second if block. The code you want would probably be this (Notice the >= and <= conditions):

```java
if (player[i][1] >= 0 && player[i][1] <= 10) { // goes thru all players and their rating
    player[i][1] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

However, I will assume one more thing, which is that you want the user to enter a number between 0 and 100 for the jersey number and a number between 0 and 10 for the player's rating.

For this you should modify your code like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[][] player = new int[5][2]; // numElements = 5 elements = 5 people

    // and each array includes 2 elements(jersey # and rating);
    for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++) { // goes thru 2-D array

        int userInput = -1;

        // Keep asking the user to provide input until they enter a vaild number
        while (!(userInput >= 0 && userInput <= 99)) {
            System.out.println("Enter player " + (i + 1) + "'s jersey number:");

            // Read user input
            userInput = scanner.nextInt();
        } // end of while loop (input)

        // Set Jersey number to user input
        player[i][0] = userInput;

        // Reset holder variable for user input
        userInput = -1;

        // Keep asking the user to provide input until they enter a vaild number
        while (!(userInput >= 0 && userInput <= 10)) {
            System.out.println("Enter player " + (i + 1) + "'s rating:");
            userInput = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        player[i][1] = userInput;

        System.out.println("");
    } // end of for loop

    System.out.println("ROSTER");

    for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
        System.out
                .println("Player " + (i + 1) + " -- Jersey number: " + player[i][0] + ", Rating: " + player[i][1]);
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
ROSTER
Player 1 -- Jersey number: 84, Rating: 7
Player 2 -- Jersey number: 23, Rating: 4
Player 3 -- Jersey number: 4, Rating: 5
Player 4 -- Jersey number: 30, Rating: 2
Player 5 -- Jersey number: 66, Rating: 9
```

Notice that the reading of user input was moved into a while loop. This forces the user to provide input fulfilling the given conditions (for the conditions I just used your `if` conditions, but negated them). I also assign the user input to a temporary variable, instead of directly to the player array.

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it a little more now. Quick question, why did you initialize userInput to -1?

Comment: @TruliTori If you do not initialize the variable with a value the compiler will complain that you are comparing, `userInput >= 0`, an uninitialized variable: `The local variable userInput may not have been initialized`. Since we have to initialize `userInput` with some value, I chose `-1`. Why `-1`? Every value for `userInput` that is outside of the values you check for in your while condition would work. But `-1` symbolizes an **invalid** input, given the context. If you chose 101 for example, it would work just fine, but logically 101 is so close to a valid value, that it might confuse you.

Comment: To add to my comment above: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170694/why-error-codes-are-negated Using negative numbers to imply error or invalid states / values has some history in software development.